# Setup and Use ClamAV (anti-virus) with Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, antivirus

I want to scan the files that are uploaded to my Azure blob.  It looks like ClamAV (www.clamav.net) is probably the way to go.  I see instructions on how to install on a Windows server, but what would my procedure be for a site hosted on Azure?  I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used ClamAV. Having said that...

You should be able to install it during a startup task (with elevated privileges). I looked at the ClamAV wiki, and it appears that the msi has a silent-install:

```
msiexec /i clamAV.msi /qr
```

You'll need to change that last parameter to /qn to force "no user interface."

The challenge will be scanning blobs. You'll need to copy files from their blobs to a local directory in your VM instance, and then run clamdscan on that file (basing off the wiki).

I haven't tried this, but the basic premise should hold up: Install anything requiring an MSI as a startup task (probably needs elevated mode).

Comment: Could one use cloud-drive to map to the storage account and scan that way?

Comment: You can map a cloud drive. However, you can't overlay the cloud drive over other blobs. It would be its own blob with a vhd (and NTFS partition). You could then set up that Cloud Drive for on-demand scanning, but you'd still need to copy files into it, if people are uploading files to individual blobs.

Comment: I don't think I need to scan a blob, do I?  I think I'm scanning a Stream InputStream of (HttpPostedFileBase object).  Does that make things easier?

Comment: If you're pretty sure this is the right direction, do you have links on how to run command line and installers on Azure?  Also, any links re the Cloud Drive / VHD / partition stuff?  I know how to publish my ASP.NET project to Azure, but I don't know server-admin stuff for Azure. Thanks.