# How to setup ClamAV in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, nclam

I want to setup ClamAV IN AZURE, went through

[Setup and Use ClamAV (anti-virus) with Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121337/setup-and-use-clamav-anti-virus-with-azure)

http://www.webdevbros.net/2015/09/02/3-easy-steps-to-scanning-files-for-viruses-in-mvc-and-for-free/

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/running-clamav-antivirus-software-in-windows-azure

http://architectryan.com/2011/05/19/nclam-a-dotnet-library-to-virus-scan/#.VgOMc9-qpBc

plus some sample projects as well. Currently I mange to run it local and solution is working as I expected. Now the problem is how I can host clamav in azure site.( I don’t have VM). Tried to install using azure command line, but cannot install uploaded exe files. 
I just want to know how I can setup clamAV in azure.

Comment: What type of Azure?  Cloud service, VM or WebApp? Hint: you'll probably need a VM, which you say you don't have.  Can you switch to a VM?

Comment: Hi Brendan Thanks for your comment. I don’t have VM. Yes you are right we are on webapp. To do those kind of process do we need VM in Azure?.

Comment: You can possibly use a cloud service (and perform the install as a startup task) or use a VM.

Comment: I don’t think that I can do with cloud service because has to include db/ folder for the virus data base plus its have few applications. so its doughty to create a package with all of those necessaries?.